# UIButton image pixelated

Tags: ios, swift3, uibutton

I can't get my UIButton image to not end up pixelated. The original image is 432X417 and my button size is 18X17. I'm setting up the button in interface builder and setting the content mode to `aspect fit`.

Comment: Use [Vector graphics in iOS](http://www.programmingcrew.in/2016/09/vector-graphics-in-ios.html)

Comment: You are not supposed to have a 432X417 (**!!!**) pixel image inside a small 18X17 button.

Comment: @pkc456 I'm using a pdf that I scaled down to the size I need then added it to an image asset at single scale and its still coming up pixelated.

Comment: @Brosef, How you create the pdf? (a) From svg (b) From png to direct scale down ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely should NOT try to install a 432x417 pixel images into a 18x17 point button.

You should create your image at the target size(s) in an image editor (e.g. Photoshop) and install that into your asset catalog. Remember that for most devices an 18x17 point images will need to be 36x34 pixels for 2x retina, and 54x51 pixels for the @3x scaled needed for the 6+ and 7+ devices.

If the image is a vector PDF then it should scale well, although 18x17 points is quite small and hard to show much detail.

Comment: Thanks for the info Duncan. So if I have one big image at lets say 500X500 pixels. I'll need to scale that down to the size I need and add it to my xcode project? I thought the point of `aspectFit` was that it would scale the image down to fit the size of the image view.

Comment: It will, but (a) it may not do a very good job, and (b), it takes a LOT more memory to give it a large image. It has to expand the large image into 4 bytes per pixel, then create another 4 bytes/pixel buffer for the scaled image, and (c) it is slower, because it has to keep rendering the large image into the smaller size.

Comment: If the original image is a vector image you will get MUCH better results rendering it directly to the target sizes than you will taking an oversized bitmap of the vector image and scaling it down.

Comment: In general, scaling an image down works well. However, when the size change is large and/or target size is very small the results tend to be poor.

Comment: I always assumed a large high resolution image would scale down to any size without issue. Lesson learned.